# GIMP doesn't show Tools window

Tags: 13.04, gimp

I have installed GIMP 2.8.4 on Ubuntu 13.04 (via standard repositories). My problem is I don't see Tools window (the one I used to show/hide with the Tab key). How can I make Tools window appear?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I have this problem as well. Sometimes the tools window is inside another screen.

**Shortcut:**

<kbd>Ctrl + B</kbd>

Try the following.

- under the <kbd>Windows</kbd> tab click <kbd>Single Window Mode</kbd>
- if the tools window isn't inside the main window, use the <kbd>Windows</kbd> tab  again and click <kbd>Dockable dialogs</kbd>  → <kbd>Tool options</kbd>.

If the tools and layer box didn't go inside your main gimp window  try toggling the <kbd>Single Window Mode</kbd>. This helps sometimes.

Comment: Thanks, now I have my Tool Options back! That's quite a magic trick; did you figure it yourself?

Comment: No problem and Yes, a lot of playing around ha-ha.

Comment: But how do I make Toolbox appear?

Comment: If the toolbox isnt there you can press "Control B" or you can under "windows" than  select option "ToolBox".

Comment: Also, make sure that you didn't accidentally press `Tab` because it is equivalent of `Windows -> Hide docks`.

Answer (score 30):

From the GIMP menu select **Windows -> Toolbox**

Shortcut **Ctrl + B**

Answer (score 17):

Make sure you don't have the `Windows`->`Hide docks` option enabled.

Comment: Why is this downvoted so much?

Comment: This one actually helped me.

Comment: This was my problem, been searching for ages. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

From GIMP 2.8.10, the menu changed a little bit:
From the GIMP menu you can open the toolbox in 2 ways:

**Windows -> New Toolbox**

**Tools -> New Toolbox**

Shortcut still works:

**Ctrl + B**

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the problem was caused by trying to display Brightness/Contrast window on an index color profile which Gimp does not allow.  Switching to the single-window mode as illustrated in the accepted answer made [the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D3TJl.png) easier to find.  The solution was slightly different in my case: Convert the image to RGB via Image, Mode, RGB and then try again to show the Brightness/Contrast dialog.

Answer (score 0):

If you are opening the Gimp Toolbox with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>B</kbd> because you do not see it and after closing and restarting Gimp the Toolbox is not showing again, check that **Windows > Hide docks** option is not selected.
Unchecking this will allow the Gimp Toolbox to be shown on a new start.

Answer (score 0):

Tab will show/hide "Docks". Or right click anywhere in the interface, which will bring up "Windows".. then everything everyone else said.

This was my issue.